# Concat selector in jQuery with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove each row in a table by its id. But, how can I concatenate the row selector with a variable? This is the jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-tambah').click(function() {
    var html = $(this).closest("tr").clone().find('td:last').after("<td id='action'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-hapus'>Hapus</button></td>").remove().end().prop('outerHTML');
    $("#daftar-buku-dipinjam").append(html);

    $('tr').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).index() + 1;
      $(this).attr("id", id);
      $('.btn-hapus').click(function() {
        $('#daftar-buku-dipinjam tr td #' + id).parent().remove(); // how to concatenate the selector?
      });
    });

    $('tr td').each(function() {
      $(this).attr("name", "bukudipinjam[]");
    });

    $('tr #action').each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("name");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="daftar-buku-dipinjam">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Judul</th>
      <th scope="col">Penulis</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td> <a href="">Hapus</a> </td>
    </tr>
    -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if the button is in a cell of the row to be removed just change  `$('#daftar-buku-dipinjam tr td #' + id)` with `$(this)`

Comment: but it will delete `<td><button>...</button></td>`

Comment: it will delete the row. as you requested. Post an example of the table otherwise

Comment: Please [edit] your question show an example of the HTML on which the code shown is supposed to work.

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique to the entire document; it appears as though the ID "action" is not unique, which will cause problems.